# Why is the last element of my array returning a large negative number?

Tags: c

I have the following code which successfully compiles on my machine.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define len(array) ( sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]) )

int main() {
    int array[5];
    /*array[4] = 1;  sorry, left in when attempting to debug*/
    int leng = len(array);
    for (int i = 0; i < leng; i++) {
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    }
}
```

For some reason, I am getting numbers like `-528721576` as the last value of the array on my machine.  Running this on an online compiler results in the correct output of `0 0 0 0 0`.  Any ideas as to what's going on with my computer?

I was expecting the output `0 0 0 0 0`.  But I get `0 0 0 0 -528721576`.

Comment: Better use different identifiers for macro and array name. You have `array` in both cases. And macros usually are with capital letters.

Comment: Why did you expect `0 0 0 0 0` if you've just assigned `1` to `array[4]`?

Comment: "the correct output of 0 0 0 0 0" As you do not initialize your local array, there is no *correct* output. The content is indetermined. Anything could be stored in that memory. Only the value of `array[4]` is set in your code. Everything else is "random".

Comment: What did you set the values of `array[0]`, `array[1]`, `array[2]` and `array[3]` to? Looks like you are using an object with *automatic storage duration* while its values is *indeterminate* (in-short -- that is UB)

Comment: Do you have a link where you put that into an online compiler? If you get all `0`, then the compiler is broken or it is not what you show us here. I would assume you have some typo in the code you show us. There is no reason why the last value should be anything different than `1` as it is the only value that is not indetermined.

Comment: The source code doesn't match the described output. Why do you expect `0 0 0 0 0`? Do you think `array[4] = 1;` does nothing, or puts a zero somewhere, or something?

Comment: thanks everyone, yes i accidentally left that line in as i was debugging.  @Gerhardh seems to have answered my question.  I thought that arrays were initialized to 0 automagically in C, but it appears not!  Thanks!

Comment: thanks @i486.  all capitals for the everything after ```#define``` or just the identifiers?

Comment: @KellyBrower Only identifier like `LEN(a)` in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When used inside a function `int array[5];` does not initialize the array, and no code in the example after the edit of 2023-07-04 17:23:17Z assigns any value to the array elements. Per the C standard, the array elements have *indeterminate* values, which is specified to mean that a C implementation may use any value of the type each type an element is used. For example:

```
printf("%d\n", array[0]);
printf("%d\n", array[0]);
printf("%d\n", array[0]);
```

would be allowed, under the standard, to print “0”, “-528721576”, and “34”. The C standard does not require the array element to have any fixed value; it is allowed to appear to be different each time it is used.

What often happens in practice is the program generated by the compiler may print values that are in memory where the array values would be stored if they had been initialized. Sometimes this memory contains zeros because nothing earlier in the program has used the stack yet. Sometimes this memory contains other values left over from prior program code, including the start-up code that executes before `main` is called. The manifestations of both “0 0 0 0 -0” and “ 0 0 0 0 -528721576” are consistent with these behaviors.

However, optimization by the compiler and other effects can cause other behaviors. For example, the program may print values from processor registers instead of from memory.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughtful answer.  It looks like some are finding this helpful, including me :)